# Is it possible to mount associated path to WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I used `subst R: .` for a faster way to access a folder.

Is it possible to mount the `R:` "drive" to WSL? When I try running `sudo mkdir /mnt/r` then `sudo mount -t ntfs R: /mnt/r`, I am met with this error:

```
ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume 'R:': No such file or directory

ntfs-3g 2017.3.23AR.3 integrated FUSE 28 - Third Generation NTFS Driver

Configuration type 7, XATTRS are on, POSIX ACLS are on
Copyright (C) 2005-2007 Yura Pakhuchiy
Copyright (C) 2006-2009 Szabolcs Szakacsits
Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Jean-Pierre Andre
Copyright (C) 2009 Erik Larsson 

Usage:    ntfs-3g [-o option[,...]] <device|image_file> <mount_point>

Options:  ro (read-only mount), windows_names, uid=, gid=,
umask=, fmask=, dmask=, streams_interface=.
Please see the details in the manual (type: man ntfs-3g).

Example: ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows

News, support and information:  http://tuxera.com
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a decent question with (I believe) a fairly straightforward answer.  Unfortunately, it's off topic for Stack Overflow, where questions should be regarding *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."*  I'd recommend posting this over on the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com).  If you do, leave a comment here with a link to the question so I can reply there (although I do watch the `windows-subsystem-for-linux` tag there, too).

Comment: Sorry about that! [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629400/is-it-possible-to-mount-associated-path-to-wsl) is the link to the same question on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange!